# baseFontSize doesn't change size of all elements

Tags: gatsby

I'm really new to Gatsby and React and I'm doing [the tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-two/). I discover typography.js, and at some point, they say

> ### Try changing the baseFontSize to 24px then 12px. All elements get resized as their font-size is based on the `baseFontSize`.

As you might have expected, it doesn't and I really don't undertand why.

Here is my `typography.js` file:

```
import Typography from "typography";

const typography = new Typography({ baseFontSize: "52px" });

export default typography;
```

// `index.js` :

```
import React from "react";

export default () =>
    <div style={{ margin: '3rem auto', maxWidth: 600 }}>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <div>
            <p>
                From Richard Hamming’s classic and must-read talk, “<a 

href="http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~robins/YouAndYourResearch.html">
                        You and Your Research
            </a>”.
          </p>

            </div>
        </div>
```

and `gatsby-config.js`

```
    module.exports = {
        plugins: [
            {
                resolve: `gatsby-plugin-typography`,
                options: {
                    pathToConfigModule: `src/utils/typography.js`,
                },
            },
        ],
    };
```

When I change the `baseFontSize`, it only affects `h1` element.

Can someone explain why to me ?

Thank you

[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c1ez.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in a dependency of typography.js (fixed now) that was causing trouble. If you upgrade to the latest version of Typography.js by running `npm upgrade` the problem will be fixed. See this issue for more details https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/5166